# Does Servicestack.Redis support cluster enabled redis?

Tags: .net, caching, redis, servicestack, cluster-computing

Can anybody give the information whether ServiceStack.Redis support cluster enabled redis or not? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it only supports [Redis Sentinel](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) via the [RedisSentinel class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-sentinel) not [Redis Cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial).

Comment: Very sad, do you suggest any .net client rather than StackExchange.Redis which support cluster, currently StackExchange have some timeout issues

Comment: @HumayunAhmed it’s very unlikely that there’d be any other mature c# client that supports Redis cluster natively, you could look at using a “Redis cluster proxy” like [twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) which provides transparent partitioning that can be used with normal Redis clients.